# Bootstrap CSS not displaying with Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I followed [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby) tutorial from Heroku on how to create a static site with Heroku. I followed the instructions exactly, but added `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` to my Gemfile. Then I tried use bootstraps Grayscale template, but it does not display properly at all. You can view my project [here](https://secure-badlands-8330.herokuapp.com/). It appears some of the CSS looks alright (color), but for the most part it is garbage.

The only eyebrow raising error I got when I ran `heroku logs` was this:

```
[2014-03-01 01:29:52] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
[2014-03-01 01:29:52] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-03-01 01:29:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `heroku logs -t` to tail the logs. Use this to see what is happening in real time as you attempt to access your site.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with heroku and boostrap, where heroku was not displaying ANY css, bootstrap or otherwise.  this was the proposed solution in the tutorial I have been following(ruby.railstutorial.org), and it seems to have done the trick:

```
# This should only be used if your Heroku deploy fails without it.
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Add precompiled assets for Heroku"
```